# Show that $\max_{P_X : X\in (0,1) } \left| \frac{\mathbb{E} [ f'(X) ]}{ \mathbb{E} [ f(X) ] } \right|$ is maximized by at most two mass points

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, linear-programming, topological-vector-spaces, global-optimization

Let $f$ be some given well-behaved function. Consider the following optimization problem overall probability distribution on $[0,1]$
\begin{align}
\max_{P_X : X\in  [0,1] }  \left|  \frac{\mathbb{E} [ f'(X) ]}{ \mathbb{E} [ f(X) ] } \right|
\end{align}
Assume that $f$ is differential and $ a<f(x) < b$.

Can we show that the maximizing distribution here is discrete with at most one or two points?

Here is my thinking:
\begin{align}
&\max_{P_X : X\in  (0,1) }  \left|  \frac{\mathbb{E} [ f'(X) ]}{ \mathbb{E} [ f(X) ] } \right|\\
 &=  \max_{P_X : X\in  (0,1) }  \left|  \int f'(x)  \frac{dP(x)} { \mathbb{E} [ f(X) ] }  \right| \\
&= \max_{ \mu : {\rm supp}(\mu) \in  (0,1) }  \left|  \int f'(x)  d \mu(x)  \right|
\end{align}
where $\mu = \frac{P}{\mathbb{E} [ f(X) ]}$ now is not a probability measure anymore but a non-negative measure.

The above is almost a linear optimization problem, but we have an absolute value. I am not sure how to handle that part.  We do know that linear programs are maximized at the extreme points. We also know that the extreme points of the measures supported on intervals are point measures.  This is why I think the optimizer has at most two mass points.

Comment: can you ask a precise question please? what is $f$?

Comment: @mathworker21 Ok. I added what we can assume about $f$.  But I don't think that the structure of $f$ as long as it is reasonable impacts the answer to the question.  I might be wrong.

Comment: The issue in your thinking is the second equality: $P/\mathbb E[f(X)]$ is a (nonnegative) measure, but not every measure $\mu$ can be obtained by some choice of $P$. So the second two maximizations (over $P$ and over $\mu$) are not equivalent.

Comment: In fact, the distribution should be concentrated at one point: If $M=\max |f'/f|$, then clearly $|Ef'|\le E|f'|\le M|Ef|$ for any $P$. On the other hand, we can achieve this value if we concentrate $P$ at the (a) maximum.

Comment: This assumes that $f>0$, but if $f$ takes both signs, then we can again concentrate $P$ at a zero $f$.